# AWS S3 PHP: Tons of Inconsistent 408 and cURL 28 Errors, Timeouts/Delays/Hangs every few seconds

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Background: I have a 250 GB object storage at Dreamhost. I am using the AWS S3 Client (PHP) for uploading files to it. It worked fine for months until they migrated their server from the West Coast to the East Coast. The only changes (very small and simple) to my scripts was a new Host URL/region. My bucket has around 1 million photos/thumbnails of around 10kb-100kb in size on average.

Since then for 2 months, some photos will upload fine, and then half the time, uploading a photo will result in 400/500 errors. We contacted Dreamhost Support and they have been absolutely stumped for 2 months - no answer to the problem. Here are type of errors in our logs:

```
[05-Dec-2018 12:28:27 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception' with message 'Error executing "PutObject" on "https://objects-us-east-1.dream.io/mybucket/img.jpg"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `PUT https://objects-us-east-1.dream.io/mybucket/img.jpg` resulted in a `408 Request Time-out` response:
<html><body><h1>408 Request Time-out</h1>
Your browser didn't send a complete request in time.
</body></html>

(client):  - <html><body><h1>408 Request Time-out</h1>
Your browser didn't send a complete request in time.
</body></html>
'

GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `PUT https://objects-us-east-1.dream.io/mybucket/img.jpg` resulted in a `408 Request Time-out` response:
<html><body><h1>408 Request Time-out</h1>
Your browser didn't send a complete request in time.
</body></html>

 in /home/username/mysite.com/includes/cdn/aws/GuzzleHttp/Exception/RequestException.php:113
 in /home/username/mysite.com/includes/cdn/aws/Aws/WrappedHttpHandler.php on line 191



[05-Dec-2018 12:44:21 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception' with message 'Error executing "PutObject" on "https://objects-us-east-1.dream.io/mybucket/img.jpg"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 0 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)'

GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 0 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) in /home/username/mysite.com/includes/cdn/aws/GuzzleHttp/Handler/CurlFactory.php:186
Stack trace:
#0 /home/username/mysite.com/includes/cdn/aws/GuzzleHttp/Handler/CurlFactory.php(150): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::createRejection(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Array)
#1 /home/username/mysite.com/includes/cdn/aws/GuzzleHttp/Handler/CurlFactory.php(103): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finishError(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\H in /home/username/mysite.com/includes/cdn/aws/Aws/WrappedHttpHandler.php on line 191
```

In an attempt to narrow down the problem, I've also done the simplest of examples like listing buckets (Dreamhost tutorial examples), and the same behavior happens - even on a new test bucket with 1 image in it. If I refresh the browser once every few seconds it might list the buckets 2-3 times successfully, but on the 4th refresh, the page continues to "hang" for a long time and it might finally display the bucket after a 150 seconds delay, or the script might just timeout. Dreamhost noticed the same thing when they set up an example on a basic cloud server instance: the bucket list might load immediately, or after 60 seconds, 120 seconds, 180 seconds, etc. A clue: seems like it loads just after 30 second increments. (these 180, 150, 120, 60 times are all divisible by 30).

I'm hoping someone understands what is happening here. The problem is so bad that we have hundreds of unhappy merchants in our marketplace that are having a hard time listing new products for sale, because of this image uploading issue making it nearly impossible for them to list images and is causing their browsers to "hang". To make matters worse, these image uploading timeout issues are causing all my 40 PHP processes to timeout, which indirectly causes 500 Internal Server Errors for site visitors as well. Our site doesn't have *that* much traffic, maybe 10,000 visitors per day. Again, it is surprising that Dreamhost has been stumped for months, they say I'm the only customer they have that has the issue.

Other info, my server is running on: 
Ubuntu 16.04
Apache 2.4.33
PHP-FPM (7.0)
cURL 7.47.0
AWS S3 SDK for PHP 3.81.0
Have HTTPS and HTTP/2 enabled

Comment: The 30 seconds thing makes me wonder if it's a DNS lookup timing out.

Comment: Thanks for the clue, I could pass this on to Dreamhost. Their support team originally suspected it was some kind of network problem, but they've been looking for 2 months and cannot find anything. They basically said there really wasn't anything else they could do for me, they hit a dead end.

Comment: I don't know if this issue is ongoing for you, but have you tried either specifying the region of the S3 bucket(s) within the S3Connection string or using the AWS S3 CLI?  The former may speed up connection speed a bit and the latter may be slower but more reliable.